# MATLAB Invalid Simulink object name, parfor and load_system

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, simulink, parfor

I try to run a model in a loop using `parfor` command.

[image: mymodel]

So I wrote the following code:

```
% control_model.m
warning('off', 'Simulink:Engine:UsingDefaultMaxStepSize');
apool = gcp('nocreate');
if isempty(apool)
    apool = parpool('local');
end

load_system('mymodel');

tic
parfor w=1:10
    warning('off', 'Simulink:Engine:UsingDefaultMaxStepSize');
    w_str=num2str(w);
    set_param('mymodel/mysystem','sys', ['tf(',w_str,',[1 ',w_str,'])'] )
    sim('mymodel',[],[])
    drawnow
end
toc

close_system('mymodel',0);
% delete(poolobj)
```

Then I will get the following error:

> Error using control_model (line 11)
>
> Invalid Simulink object name: mymodel/mysystem

If I run it again, I get the same error (Although using `for` instead of `parfor` solves this error).

But if I put a `load_system('mymodel');` just after `parfor` and run it once, the problem is fixed. And even if I remove `load_system` command, the error is not shown for the next times anymore.

I am interested in knowing what is happening behind the scene and why the first `load_system` does not solve the problem even if I run the program so many times. while the one in `parfor` fix the problem even if being removed in the next time calling the script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to load the model on the worker (see [sim in parfor with Normal Mode](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/running-parallel-simulations.html#bt33wws) in the documentation for more details), so your `load_system` needs to be within the `parfor` loop:

```
tic
parfor w=1:10
    load_system('mymodel');
    warning('off', 'Simulink:Engine:UsingDefaultMaxStepSize');
    w_str=num2str(w);
    set_param('mymodel/mysystem','sys', ['tf(',w_str,',[1 ',w_str,'])'] )
    sim('mymodel',[],[])
    drawnow
end
toc
```

Comment: The question is why next times it works even without `load_system`

Comment: @ar2015 Difficult to answer this one, but I suspect that once the model is loaded on the worker once, it remains loaded for subsequent iterations (unless of course it's overwritten by loading another model or closing the loaded one). The answer to be sure that the model is correctly loaded for every single iteration remains to put the `load_system` inside the `parfor`.